# how i solve django 3.x admin autocomplete error

Tags: django

I have tried `python manage.py collectstatic` but no effect.It seems to be the problem about app_label from error message.
I sure i have all  permissions.
Configuration about autocomplete all in admin.
I only diplay partial code in UserAds and Adset,these are all code about this error
these are  my Admin and Model：

```
class SKUAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = UserAds
    list_display = ('owner', 'astype','order_id', 'timerange', 'is_active','thumb' )
    actions = ['make_is_active','make_batch_delete']
    inlines = [ImageadInline,]
    autocomplete_fields = ["astype",]
    search_fields = ('owner__username', 'title', )
class ADsetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model=ADset
    search_fields = ("slug",)
    list_display = ('name', 'slug', 'price','thumbnail','adtype')
class UserAds(BaseModel):
    astype = models.ForeignKey(ADset,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=False,null=True,,related_name='addetail')
...

class ADset(BaseModel):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=40,blank=True,null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True,  max_length=100)
    seq = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    size=models.JSONField(blank=True,null=True)
    price=models.DecimalField(blank=True,null=True,max_digits=12, decimal_places=2 )
    oldprice = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, )
    default_image_url = models.ImageField(upload_to="defaultads/" , null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ads_set'      
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name+self.slug
```

this is the Traceback:

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 76, in __getitem__
    list_ = super().__getitem__(key)
>KeyError: 'app_label'

>During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/autocomplete.py", line 61, in process_request
    app_label = request.GET['app_label']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 78, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'app_label'

>The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 232, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 417, in autocomplete_view
    return AutocompleteJsonView.as_view(admin_site=self)(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/autocomplete.py", line 20, in get
    self.term, self.model_admin, self.source_field, to_field_name = self.process_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/autocomplete.py", line 65, in process_request
    raise PermissionDenied from e
django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied
```

Comment: Can you add the `admin.py` and the `models.py` for the model that has the `autocomplete` configuration and for the model referenced by the autocomplete? Are you using any third-party packages and do you have view and change permissions for the related model?

Comment: i view django permission table， i sure i have those permissions that you said.  I know this error is about Key error: app_label,but I don't konw how and where add app_label attribult

Comment: The `admin.py` and `models.py` for the models requested above may help identify the issue, please add them to the question not as comments

Comment: admin and model have been in there.

Comment: Thanks, can you add the same for `ADset` too? The related model/admin is what is used to generate the autocomplete response

Comment: i have done for you said

Comment: Your models and admin look fine, thanks. The next thing to check is that the AJAX request is hitting the correct URL, when you trigger the autocomplete in the admin (by clicking the select for the `astype` field) can you see the URL accessed in your browser devtools network tab? It should be something like `/admin/autocomplete/?app_label=foo&model_name=adset&field_name=astype`

Comment: thanks,but i view AJAX requests url is "../autocomplete/“ ，but i don't change autocomplete.js of django,